# Render map to a hidden div

Tags: openlayers

I want to display the results of a query on a map. I have a hidden div in which I am going to render the map that will be shown when I click on the button that executes the query. The problem is that when I click on the **btnMapa** button, the div is shown, but not the map and I only see the map if I resize the browser screen.
My HTML and JS code is more o less simple:

```
<div class="btnmapa" id="btnMapa"></div>
<div class = "table">
    <div class = "map" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

My ol code:

```
var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    zoom:7,
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZoom:7,
    center:[-5.999, 43.606, 6.132, -44.918 ]
});

var layers=[osm];
var map= new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view:view,
    layers: layers,
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      zoom: false,
      attribution: false,
      rotate: false,
    }),
});
```

CSS code

```
.map {height:500px;margin: 0; padding: 10px;width:100%;    }
.table{width: 100%;display:none;clear:both;}
```

Comment: After unhiding the div call `map.updateSize()`

Comment: Also, I didn't see the query run until I did the resize. Using map.updateSize() works perfectly. Thanks @Mike